# Lipschitz continuous function with derivative coinciding with continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz continuous function. Since $f$ is Lipschitz, $f$ is absolutely continuous, and thus $Df$ is defined almost everywhere. Suppose $Df$ coincides with a continuous function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$. I am trying to prove that $f$ is $C^1$ with $Df=g$.

The proof to this is simple with $n=1$. We use the fact $f(x)-f(a)=\int_a^x f'(y) dy$, which implies $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ converges as $x\to a$. I have trouble creating a proof for $n>1$, however.  Any hints to this problem are appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit**: I think I have come up with a proof, although it is probably overkill.

Let $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$. We will show $f$ is $C^1$ in a closed ball $B(a,r)$ for $r>0$. Let $f^\epsilon:=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\eta_\epsilon(x-y)f(y)dy$ be the convolution of $f$, where $\eta_\epsilon:=\frac{1}{\epsilon^n}\eta(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$ and $\eta(x)$ is a positive symmetric mollifier. $f^\epsilon$ converges uniformly to $f$ in $B(a,r)$. Because $(f^\epsilon)_{x_i}=(f_{x_i})^\epsilon$ in $L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $i$, $(f^\epsilon)_{x_i}$ uniformly converges to $g_i$ in $B(a,r)$. Because $C^1(B(a,r))$ is complete with respect to the norm

$||f||_{C^1(B(a,r))}:=||f||_{L^\infty(B(a,r))}+|||Df|||_{L^\infty(B(a,r))}$,

and $f^\epsilon$ is convergent in this norm as $\epsilon\to 0$, the limit function, $f$, is in $C^1(B(a,r))$.

Comment: Doesn't $C^1$ mean that $Df$ is a continuous function?

Comment: @RickSanchez: I am only assuming that there exists a continuous function $g$ such that $Df=g$ on the set that $Df$ is defined. Since $f$ is Lipschitz, this set is almost all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I am not sure if this implies $Df$ itself is continuous.